# GPIO Event Detect triggers the wrong event

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi

I am building a help button system on Raspberry PI that when a button is pressed a wav file is played over the PA system.
I have copied some code from here: [Raspberry PI with GPIO Input buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34208951/raspberry-pi-with-gpio-input-buttons)
which works pretty well except the following.  If I press button 1 I get sound 1 playing as expected.  When I then press button 2 I get sound 1 playing.
If at program start I press button 2 first then I do get sound 2 playing but if I push button 1 then I get sound 2 playing.
Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#coding: utf8

import time 
from time import sleep
import os
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.IN)

try:
    vtc1 = 7       # Time Audiofile 1
    vtc2 = 6       # Time Audiofile 2
    
    vtc = 0         # Current AudioFileTime
    started_t = 0   # Started Time

    while True:     
        if GPIO.input(23) and time.time() - started_t > vtc:
            vtc = vtc1
            started_t = time.time()
            print("Button 1 Pressed")
            os.system('omxplayer -o local /audio_project/sound_1.WAV &')
        time.sleep(0.200)

        if GPIO.input(24) and time.time() - started_t > vtc:
            vtc = vtc2
            started_t = time.time()
            print("Button 2 Pressed")
            os.system('omxplayer -o local /audio_project/sound_2.WAV &')
        time.sleep(0.200)
except:
    print("Other error or exception occurred!")
finally:
    GPIO.cleanup() # this ensures a clean exit
```

How can I get this to play the correct file on second button push?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I found what was at fault.  I had added pull down resistors to the GPIO pins but I had inadvertently missed adding the jumper from these resistors to Ground!  Oops.  Once this was connected it worked a charm.